# How can I filter xml sections and save it as a file

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I am a beginner in using LINQ. I have an xml data with the format below

```
<Root>
    <Global>
    </Global>
    <local>
        <element name="A">
            <subelement name="A">
                <element name="A1">
                    <subelement name="A1">
                        <Property>
                        </Property>
                    </subelement>
                </element>
                <element name="B">
                    <Property>
                    </Property>
                </element>
            </subelement>
            <subelement name="B">
                <element name="A">
                    <Property>
                    </Property>
                </element>
                <element name="B">
                    <Property>
                    </Property>
                </element>
            </subelement>
        </element>
    </local>
</Root>
```

I want to save each section of the **Property** element into it's own xml file as below while keeping the hierarchy structure intact

```
<Root>
    <Global>
    </Global>
    <local>
        <element name="A">
            <subelement name="A">
                <element name="A1">
                    <subelement name="A1">
                        <Property>
                        </Property>
                </subelement>
                </element>
            </subelement>
        </element>
    </local>
</Root>
```

and

```
<Root>
    <Global>
    </Global>
    <local>
        <element name="A">
            <subelement name="A">
                <element name="B">
                    <Property>
                    </Property>
                </element>
            </subelement>
        </element>
    </local>
</Root>
```

and so on for all the **Property** elements. Each **element** can have a child **subelement** and each **subelement** can have **element** child

Can you provide a solution on how to save each section of **Property** element as a new xml file with the current hierarchy structure intact. I have tried using the Ancestor() method of the XElement class

```
XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(filename);
XDocument convertedQuery = new XDocument(
        new XElement(xml.Root.Name, from x in xml.Descendants("local")
                                    select x.Ancestors())
         );
```

but it is returning other **Property** elements as well, as below

```
<Root>
<Global></Global>
<local>
  <element name="A">
    <subelement name="A">
      <element name="A1">
        <subelement name="A1">
          <Property></Property>
        </subelement>
      </element>
      <element name="B">
        <Property></Property>
      </element>
    </subelement>
    <subelement name="B">
      <element name="A">
        <Property></Property>
      </element>
      <element name="B">
        <Property></Property>
      </element>
    </subelement>
  </element>
</local>
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some C# sample that should do what you want or at least give you an idea on how to approach that. The sample for testing simply writes each created `XDocument` to `Console.Out` but of course you could change that to save to a file on disk:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"..\..\XMLFile1.xml");
    foreach (XElement prop in doc.Descendants("Property"))
    {
        XDocument result = new XDocument(
            new XElement(doc.Root.Name, doc.Root.Attributes(),
                doc.Root.Elements("Global"),
                CopySubtree(prop.Ancestors("local").First(), prop)));
        result.Save(Console.Out);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
static XElement CopySubtree(XElement ancestor, XElement descendant)
{
    if (ancestor == descendant)
    {
        return descendant;
    }
    else
    {
        return
            new XElement(
                ancestor.Name, 
                ancestor.Attributes(), 
                CopySubtree(
                  ancestor
                  .Elements()
                  .First(e => e.DescendantsAndSelf().Any(d => d == descendant)),
                  descendant));
    }
}
```

[edit]
For the new requirement to copy not only the Property ancestors but also its siblings you could adapt above method as follows:

```
static XElement CopySubtree(XElement ancestor, XElement descendant)
{
    if (ancestor == descendant.Parent)
    {
        return ancestor;
    }
    else
    {
        return
            new XElement(
                ancestor.Name, 
                ancestor.Attributes(), 
                CopySubtree(
                  ancestor
                  .Elements()
                  .First(e => e.DescendantsAndSelf().Any(d => d == descendant)),
                  descendant));
    }
}
```